# Can I substitute を with に in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

In the sentence:

> 姫様を助けてあげてください

The recipient of あげて is 姫様. So can I use 姫様に to explicitly imply the recipient and omit the object of 助けて　(姫様を) and does the following sentence make sense?

> 姫様に助けてあげてください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The particle must agree with the main verb 助ける, not the subsidiary あげる.

Comment: Thanks. If the recipient of あげる and the object of 助ける are not the same，like「王様に姫様を助けてあげてください」(please help the princess for the king), is it OK？

Comment: @shepherd - No, you would need to say 王様のために姫様を to make the meaning of "for" clear. This is also true when you want to be explicit about the beneficiary of くれる (ください), like 私たちのために姫様を.

Comment: So 「王様に姫様を助けてあげてください」is ungrammatical? I just want to explicitly imply the recipient of あげる.

Comment: @shepherd - It doesn’t work that way. 王様に would be understood as another argument of 助ける but this verb doesn’t take two objects like say, 送る. (I don’t think you can “explicitly imply” something…)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand it well.  I want to use the structure: 「〜に〜してあげる」. So If I change the verb:「姫様に魔王を倒してあげてください」does it make sense and have meaning "please do the princess a favor to defeat the devil "?

Comment: @shepherd - It doesn't make sense, period. It's because 姫様に倒す is ungrammatical unless 姫様 is a destination toward which you knock down 魔王.

Comment: Sorry, but what I want to say is 姫様に(魔王を倒して)あげる, not 姫様に倒す. Even this is not grammatical?

Comment: @shepherd - As I keep telling you it doesn't work that way. The part inside the brackets in [〜に〜を V-て]-あげる has to make sense. 姫様に魔王を倒す doesn't. 〜のために falls outside of the brackets and thus modifies either あげる or ください.

Comment: Thanks！I’ve never realised the に part between てあげる should meet some certain rules. Please forgive my stupidity.